# concatenate and interpolate PHP variables for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 variables that contain a text string. I need to update them in the table, but out of the 20+ different variations of about 5 different scripts that I've tried out, it just doesn't update!
I want something like below script:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $variable_1 SET $variable_2 = $q WHERE $variable_3 = $o")
   or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: what is $variable_1, $variable_2,  $variable_3 ??

Comment: $variable_1 . is that your table name??

Comment: what is your table structure. In the code above you are using variable_1 as the table name is this what you were planning?

Comment: can You write sql query with commas around variables?

Comment: syntax error check your mysql manual to use near $variable_3 = $o

Comment: $variable_1 is my table name, $variable_2 & $variable_3 is my column name of that selected table

Comment: it results----    
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$variables_3' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET field_name = '"
    .$str_value."' WHERE $field_3 = '".$str_value.'")
  or die(mysql_error());
```